# can I use data class argument multiplication of other two arguments in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I have a data class which has 3 arguments, I need to make the third argument as the muliptlication of other two arguments.

```
data class Item(var qty: Int, var price : Double, var totalPrice : Double = qty * price){ }
```

after I create an item object   `var itemOne = Item(1, 3.70)` if I change `itemOne.qty = 2` it still gives me `itemOne.totalPrice` as `3.70`

Is there a way to do this, I mean using one of the paramater as mathemetical operation of others?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `totalPrice` should always be calculated, it shouldn't be in the constructor at all:

```kotlin
data class Item(var qty: Int, var price: Double) {
  val totalPrice: Double
    get() = qty * price
}
```

Comment: Yeah this - the price and quantity is the actual data (which is what goes in the constructor in a data class), ``totalPrice`` is a property derived from those values. There shouldn't ever be a way to modify it independently, and it doesn't need to be stored or involved in any equality/hashcode calculations

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the `item.qty` and also updating the `totalPrice` you should create new instance of `Item` to re-calculate the `totalPrice` or you could create function `updateQty`.

```kotlin
data class Item(var qty: Int, var price: Double, var totalPrice:Double) {
   fun updateQty(qty:Int){
      this.qty = qty
      this.totalPrice = qty * this.price
   }
}
```